# Screen Wake Lock ON Interactive Canvas

Tags: javascript, actions-on-google

Using the "Screen Wake Lock API", I trying to prevent the screen sleep when i playing a large music on Frontend, but i getting this error

> NotAllowedError, Failed to execute 'request' on 'WakeLock': Access to
> Screen Wake Lock features is disallowed by feature policy

```
const requestWakeLock = async () => {
    let wakeLock = null;
    try {
        wakeLock = await navigator.wakeLock.request('screen');
        wakeLock.addEventListener('release', () => {
            console.log('Wake Lock was released');
        });
        console.log('Wake Lock is active');
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(`${err.name}, ${err.message}`);
    }
};

requestWakeLock();
```

Comment: Depending on the surface you are trying to run this on, it looks like this may be blocked based on [the permissions policy](https://w3c.github.io/screen-wake-lock/#policy-control).

Comment: I know, im asking it, because the Google Developers Support said to asking here